# Переключатель как в Google переводчик

Tags: android

Как можно реализовать переключатель как в Google переводчике или на скриншоте ниже?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал так, но тексты переключаются со второго нажатия на кнопку

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int sw;

    TextView txtLeft;
    TextView txtRight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtLeft = findViewById(R.id.txtLeft);
        txtRight = findViewById(R.id.txtRight);
        ImageButton btnRef = findViewById(R.id.btnRef);

        sw = 0;
        txtLeft.setText("Русский");
        txtRight.setText("Английский");

        btnRef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (sw){
                    case 0:
                        txtLeft.setText("Русский");
                        txtRight.setText("Английский");
                        sw = 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        txtLeft.setText("Английский");
                        txtRight.setText("Русский");
                        sw = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Чего именно вы хотите добиться? Чтобы текст между кнопочками менялся или такую же кнопку поставить или чтобы по нажатию она переворачивалась?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку тексты переключались и чтобы в зависимости от того как переключены делать действия. Например если слева Русский, а справа Английский - одно действие, если наоборот то другое.

Comment: Может есть лучшее решение

Comment: Со второго раза, а потом всё нормально? Поставьте sw = 1. Сам не люблю такие задачи, их почти не возможно сделать аккуратными и изящными.

Comment: Да, потом нормально переключается.

Comment: Помогло sw = 1. Спасибо.

Comment: У вас действия будут выполняться по кнопке? Тогда для начало делайте так же как у вас только в другом участке кода: switch(sw){ case: 0 {условие 1} case: 1 {условие 2} и т.д. или if(txtLeft.getText().equals("Русский")) {условие 1} else if ("Английский") {условие 2} else if(){и т.д.}. А вообще по хорошему нужно составлять список, например Map и выполнять условия в соответствии с ним.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение покороче:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isENGRight;

    TextView txtLeft;
    TextView txtRight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtLeft = findViewById(R.id.txtLeft);
        txtRight = findViewById(R.id.txtRight);
        ImageButton btnRef = findViewById(R.id.btnRef);

        txtLeft.setText("Русский");
        txtRight.setText("Английский");

        btnRef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtRight.setText(isENGRight? "Английский":"Русский");
                txtLeft.setText(isENGRight? "Русский":"Английский");
                isENGRight = !isENGRight;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Действия можно выполнять по состоянию `isENGRight`:

```
if (isENGRight) { //перевод с русского на английский
         } else { // перевод с английского на русский
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.. это решение получше